# Perl — HTTP::Request::Common — POST file AND array

Tags: perl, post

I'm trying to POST file into a webapp endpoint. The problem is that in the same request I need to include array as a value of one of the parameters.

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $ua->post(
    $baseurl_local . 'create',
    Content_Type => 'form-data',
    Content      => [
    file =>  [$file],
    targetLang => 'french',
]);
```

works just fine.

However when I try to

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $ua->post(
    $baseurl_local . 'create',
    Content_Type => 'form-data',
    Content      => [
    file =>  [$file],
    targetLang => ['french','spanish],
]);
```

I get

> Can't open file french: No such file or directory at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/HTTP/Request/Common.pm line 154.
>   HTTP::Request::Common::form_data(ARRAY(0x6800698), undef, HTTP::Request=HASH(0x6803a70)) called at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/HTTP/Request/Common.pm line 67

It would seem Perl thinks array ref with languages is a file.

what am I doing wrong?

---

To expand on the resolution based on Matt's answer: as I forgot to mention originally, the list of languages comes from user input, so I ended up doing something like:

```
my @languages = (targetLang => 'french', targetLang => 'spanish');
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $ua->post(
    $baseurl_local . 'create',
    Content_Type => 'form-data',
    Content      => [
        file =>  [$file],
        @languages,
]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [HTTP::Request::Common docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Common):

> Multivalued form fields can be specified by either repeating the field
>   name or by passing the value as an array reference.
>
> The POST method also supports the `multipart/form-data` content used for
>   *Form-based File Upload* as specified in RFC 1867. You trigger this
>   content format by specifying a content type of `'form-data'` as one of
>   the request headers. If one of the values in the `$form_ref` is an array
>   reference, then it is treated as a file part specification...

So, while you could normally specify a multivalued field with an array reference, array references have special significance with `multipart/form-data` content, and you'll probably have to get around it by repeating the field name:

```
my $response = $ua->post(
    $baseurl_local . 'create',
    Content_Type => 'form-data',
    Content      => [
        file       => [$file],
        targetLang => 'french',
        targetLang => 'spanish',
    ],
);
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, this works.

For some reason I was not able to understand "Multivalued form fields can be specified by either repeating the field name or by passing the value as an array reference." enough to solve the problem.

Comment: @Matt jacob. Ok how can I include the authorization stuff in the request. The basic authorization is usually passed in the headers. I want to do this thing but I am confused how to put this in POST request method.